# Adding sata disk w/o controller to IBM X3400 M3

Tags: sas, sata, ibm-xseries

We have IBM X3400 M3 with SAS controller and and two disk with raid 1. We need extra space without protection. I try to add standart SATA disk to server. It has two SATA port on mainboard. When I connect SATA disk, it can't boot from SAS controller, try to boot from sata. I can't find any option in boot order for SAS controller. I try to adding SAS controller as boot device in bios but no solution.

I try to another option: buying PCIE 2.0 1x sata controller (IO-PCE9215-4I). This card hasn't got rom, only working in operation system. Amber light on near PCIE slot. I try to disable rom boot option and legacy mode for PCIE slot but no solution. System auto restart while detecting booteable adapter step.

I can't find detail about third party PCI Express sata controller or any PCI Express card working or not with IBM server.

I will making plan to test with PCI sata controller.

Is there any way to adding sata disk to this server without new IBM sas/sata controller?

Answer (score 1):

You should use second RAID controller for SATA. And this mean also second backplane because you can't split backplane to serve SAS and SATA disk. And you can't mix SATA and SAS in the same bus

EDIT: My practice show me most of the time you can't use third party controllers in branded machines. You should stay with certified controllers for particular machine.

Comment: This info already in manuals. Missing informations are: "You cannot use onboard sata controller with PCI-E SAS/SATA controller.", "You cannot use third party sata controller", "You cannot use third party PCI-E devices." etc. I am not sure we can do these or not.

Comment: @mkysoft, my practice show me most of the time you can't use third party controllers in branded machines. You should stay with certified controllers for particular machine.